# list files of a specific extension in a folder using JSP

Tags: file, jsp

```
<h1>Directories</h1>
<ul>
<%
String root="c:/Repository/WebApplication/mydocs/javadoc/";
java.io.File file;
java.io.File dir = new java.io.File(root);

String[] list = dir.list();

if (list.length > 0) {

for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
file = new java.io.File(root + list[i]);
if (file.isDirectory()) {
%>
<li><a href="javadoc/<%=list[i]%>" target="_top"><%=list[i]%></a><br>
<%
 }
}
}
%>
</ul>
```

The above code works, i.e it lists all the files, I want to list only files of specific extensions such as .txt. Can anyone pl tell me how to go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751335/using-file-listfiles-with-filenameextensionfilter

Answer (score 3):

You need a [FilenameFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) and implements it method [accept](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html#accept%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) in such a way that you accept only file witch have the extension you need.

Here is a sample code

```
new File("").list(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".txt");
        }
    });
```

Note that this code is not case sensitive, so files ending with `.TXT` will be filtered out. You may want to extract the extension and then use [equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) to compare it. Alternatively you can [LowerCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) `name` before calling [endsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<% 
    String file = application.getRealPath("/results");
    File f = new File(file);
    String [] fileNames = f.list();
    int i = 0;
    String fname=null;
    File [] fileObjects= f.listFiles();
    BufferedReader readReport;
    int num=0;

    {
        %>
        <table name="reports">
        <th width=12.5% align="center" bgcolor="gray">Execution ID</th>
        <th width=12.5% align="center" bgcolor="gray">Parent suite name</th>
        <th width=12.5% align="center" bgcolor="gray">Execution date</th>
        <th width=12.5% align="center" bgcolor="gray">Total execution time(seconds)</th>
        <th width=12.5% align="center" bgcolor="gray">Pass</th>
        <th width=12.5% align="center" bgcolor="gray">Fail</th>
        <th width=12.5% align="center" bgcolor="gray">Skip</th>
        <th width=12.5% align="center" bgcolor="gray">Summary</th>
        <%
    }

    for (i=0; i < fileObjects.length; i++)
    {

        if(!fileObjects[i].isDirectory())
            {
            fname = "../results/"+fileNames[i];

            if(fname.endsWith(".html"))
            {
                String Name = fileNames[i].substring(0, fileNames[i].indexOf('.'));


                    { 
                        %>
                        <tr bgcolor="lightgray">
                            <td width=12.5% align="center">
                                <%=Name%>
                            </td>

                            <td width=12.5% align="center">

                            </td>

                            <td width=12.5%  align="center">

                            </td>

                            <td width=12.5%  align="center">

                            </td>

                            <td width=12.5%  align="center">

                            </td>

                            <td width=12.5%  align="center">

                            </td>

                            <td width=12.5%  align="center">

                            </td> 

                            <td width=12.5%  align="center">
                                <a HREF="<%= fname %>" target="loadReport"><button>View</button></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <%
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    {%></table> <%}
%>
```

Comment: use the endswith() fnction :)

Comment: Isn't this much more code than required? What does the table have to do with the rest? Also, using `endsWith` was already suggested in another answer!