# Delete from LinkedList of Files with occurrences from an Array of allowed extensions?

Tags: java, arrays, file, linked-list

I have a LinkedList of files which I populated using the following line:

```
File file = new File(directoryPath);
List<File> filesList = new LinkedList<File>(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()));
```

This gets me all the files in given directoryPath string.

I then have an Array of the file extensions that are allowed and would like to delete any file (not directory) that's inside which doesn't match up.

```
String[] file_ext = new String[] {"ext1", "ext2", "ext3"};
```

How can I proceed to implement this?

Comment: What do you want to end up with? If one of the files is a directory do you want to search that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
final String[]  file_ext = new String[] {"ext1", "ext2", "ext3"};

FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            for(int i=file_ext.length-1;i>=0;i--)
                if( name.endsWith( "." + file_ext[i]) )
                    return true;
            return false;
        }
    };

File file = new File(directoryPath);
List<File> filesList = new LinkedList<File>(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles(filter)));
```

**Updated:**
As per 'Borsi the Spider' comment, to avoid false matches such as `files.notext1`, the searching matches the `.` character as well

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have modified to consider the searching including the `.` character

Comment: This is ultimately what I ended up with but without using a FilenameFilter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take list of files and check if they names ends with any ext from `file_ext`, if yes, add them to list of `filesToDelete`
2. Delete files from `filesToDelete` list.

Comment: Since this was the first answer I went with it, thanks everyone else for your answers too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FilenameFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html), an example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751335/using-file-listfiles-with-filenameextensionfilter)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`FileNameExtensionFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html)

```
final FileNameExtensionFilter fnef = new FileNameExtensionFilter("", "ext1", "ext2", "ext3");
final List<File> files = new LinkedList<>();
for(final File f : new File(directoryPath).listFiles()) {
    if(fnef.accept(f)) files.add(f);
}
```

This is from Swing but it does exactly what you want and it doesn't have any dependencies on the EDT or anything odd.

You could even wrap the `FileNameExtensionFilter` in a `FileFilter` façade and make it a one-liner:

```
final List<File> filesList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new File(directoryPath).listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    final FileNameExtensionFilter fnef = new FileNameExtensionFilter("", "ext1", "ext2", "ext3");

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return fnef.accept(pathname);
    }
})));
```