# Retrieve all XML file names from a directory using JAVA

Tags: java, directory, java-io

I have a directory with multiple files. I need to retrieve only XML file names in a List using Java. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried. Some code please.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751335/using-file-listfiles-with-filenameextensionfilter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, {FilePath} is directory path:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File folder = new File("{FilePath}");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for(int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++){
        String filename = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        if(filename.endsWith(".xml")||filename.endsWith(".XML")) {
            System.out.println(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `filename.endsWith(".xml")` will miss any file ending .XML.  2) Use a `FilenameFilter`!

Comment: @AndrewThompson: jus add an Or statement to if statement it works fine..!!

Comment: *"jus add an Or statement to if statement it will work fine..!!"*  I don't *have to do* anything.  OTOH since you changed that part, I'll remove the down-vote.  ***It would still be more optimal to use the defined API for it though.***

Answer (score 1):

You can use also a FilenameFilter:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class FileDemo implements FilenameFilter {
    String str;

    // constructor takes string argument
    public FileDemo(String ext) {
        str = "." + ext;
    }

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f = null;
        String[] paths;

        try {
            // create new file
            f = new File("c:/test");

            // create new filter
            FilenameFilter filter = new FileDemo("xml");

            // array of files and directory
            paths = f.list(filter);

            // for each name in the path array
            for (String path : paths) {
                // prints filename and directory name
                System.out.println(path);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // if any error occurs
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(str.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: I would change `name.endsWith(str)` to `name.toLowerCase().endsWith(str.toLowerCase())` in order to account for ..different case between what is specified, and what is found. Otherwise, +1 not only for the correct API, but an example.  Nice.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by using File.filter(FileNameFilter). Provide your implementation for FileNameFilter

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = new File("C:\\");
if (f.isDirectory()){
   FilenameFilter filter =  new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                if(name.endsWith(".xml")){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
   if (f.list(filter).length > 0){
      /* Do Something */
   }
}
```