# How can I read from a directory only the files that have a certain extension

Tags: java

For example i have a directory contains the below files:

1. test.log
2. test.html
3. test.txt

I would like to know how I can make my java program pick and read only the files with .log extension.

Because the name of the file is always changing and I want to trace and read the files that have .log extension.

Any idea ?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751335/using-file-listfiles-with-filenameextensionfilter) this should help you.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

```
File file=new File("path.log");
String name=file.toString();
String tok[]=name.split("\\.");
if(tok[tok.length-1].equals("log")){
    //compute
}
```

Above is the core logic of checking the extension for being `log`. Below code is to iterate a directory and look for a file with `log` extension.

```
File file=new File("C:/Temp/");
String name,tok[];
for(File temp:file.listFiles()){
    name=temp.toString();
    tok=name.split("\\.");
    if(tok[tok.length-1].equals("log")){
        //compute
    }
}
```

For more on `File` visit [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public boolean accept(File file) {
      return file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWidth(".log");
    }
```

Comment: To compare stings you have to use `equals` not `==`

Comment: So, what if the file is named foo.log.txt? BTW, split(".") doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You should remove the first part, which is plain wrong. The body of the accept method should be rewritten as `return file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWidth(".log");`

Comment: @Suganthan What @JBNizet is trying to tell: The [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method works on [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). So the first part is wrong _and_ unnecessary. The second part is written as `if (<boolean expression>) return true; /*else*/ return false;`. This can and should be written as a simple `return <boolean expression>;`. This is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex to match the extension of the file:

```
if(file.toString().matches(".*\\.log"))
{
    //Process the file
}
```

Comment: Why use a regex when all you need is `endsWith()`? BTW, your backslash needs to be escaped.

Comment: No, you haven't. That doesn't even compile: illegal escape character.

Comment: @user3189142 Yes, he is sure! This code snippet does not compile (because of the not escaped backslash).

Comment: @JBNizet Fixed it. In my test I didn't compile with the regex, but entered it at runtime. That's probably why I didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) (WildcardFileFilter)

```
File dir = new File("/path/to/directory");
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.log");

File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
   System.out.println(files[i]); // do something
```

Answer (score 0):

See following snippet

```
    Path path = Paths.get("resources/");
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path, "*.{zip,txt}")) {
        for (Path entry : dirStream) {
            System.out.printf("%-5s: %s%n", "entry", entry.getFileName());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
```

For more details have a look into this full example: 
https://github.com/jugsaar/jugsaar-meeting-9/blob/master/talks/java-nio2/src/main/java/de/jugsaar/meeting9/nio2/directorystream/DirectoryStreamGlobbingPatternDemo.java