# How do I get files of particular extension?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a program which upload backup files to the cloud server, I want to use wildcard characters to upload all files like "*.txt" or ".jpg".

My code is:

```
String fileWACrypt = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/backup/DMG122.jpg";
```

but I want

```
String fileWACrypt = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/backup/*.jpg";
```

Comment: Let me confirm, are you looking for a way to get all files in a folder which have a specific extension (i.e a method which returns all, say, **.txt** files in a folder)?

Comment: yes same thing i want

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using File.listFiles with FileNameExtensionFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751335/using-file-listfiles-with-filenameextensionfilter)

Comment: did not work brother

Comment: Update your question with the code.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8647397/4935567) and filter the files as you need.