# How to list files under a tomcat 6 webapp

Tags: tomcat6

I have a spring boot project that is deployed on Tomcat 6.  I have a list of files under project's resource directory and I am trying to list all files under that directory.  I am able to get specific file if I specify classpath:abc.txt in the getResource() method.  However I am wondering if there is a way to just list all files with a wild card or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do like this MyClass.class.getResource('*.txt'). The alternative to this is :

```
ServletContext      sc                      =       request.getSession().getServletContext();
    String          strPath                 =       sc.getRealPath("/");
File[]          allFiles          =       new File(strpath).listFiles(new FilenameFilter()    {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
    }
});
```

Refer this :[Using File.listFiles with FileNameExtensionFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751335/using-file-listfiles-with-filenameextensionfilter)